# Matrix multiplication in c++ in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, xtensor

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication in Android Studio and want to use c++ for the speed benefit.
I found the library xtensor and think that it will be useful but I cant get working. I tried putting the header files into the cpp folder but then they dont have access to the base library dependencies and I've been researching for hours now but I couldn't find out exactly what to write in the CMakeLists.txt and how libraries are actually meant to be installed. I'm sorry if this is really obvious but I can't really wrap my head around it.

How can I install the xtensor library in android studio or is there some other way? I wanted to avoid using for loops for the calculation but if there's no other possibility I guess I have to..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I install the xtensor library in android studio or is there some other way? I wanted to avoid using for loops for the calculation but if there's no other possibility I guess I have to..

`xtensor` project is based on `cmake` which is supported by `AndroidStudio(gradle)` so you can easily use it for NDK build.

It takes just a few steps to integrate `xtensor` into your project (without installing it into the system):

1. Fetch `xtensor` and `xtl` (`xtensor` depends on `xtl`) projects and add them to your root cmake, for example:

```
add_subdirectory(external/xtl)
add_subdirectory(external/xtensor)
```

2. Create `Findxtl.cmake` to support `find_package(xtl)`. It's enough only to set `xtl_FOUND`:

```
set(xtl_FOUND TRUE)
```

3. And the last step is to link your native library to the `xtensor` interface library:

```
add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(native-lib xtensor)
```

[Here](https://github.com/nkh-lab/ndk-xtensor) an example how it can be done for `Android Studio Native C++ Template Project` based on "Initialize a 2-D array and compute the sum of one of its rows and a 1-D array" example from [xtensor/basic-usage](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor#basic-usage).